# Sending SOAP request to service: ERROR #6237: Unexpected tag MSH (Line 5) 

Tags: web-services, http, soap, server, wsdl

Here we have the WSDL

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s0="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta" xmlns:s1="urn:hl7-org:v2xml" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta">
<types>
    <s:schema targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
        <s:element name="ACKAplicacionER7">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="mensaje" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element name="ACKAplicacionXML">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="mensaje" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element name="PeticionER7">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="mensaje" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element name="PeticionXML">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="mensaje" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
    </s:schema>
</types>
<message name="ACKAplicacionER7SoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s1:ACKAplicacionER7"/>
</message>
<message name="ACKAplicacionXMLSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s1:ACKAplicacionXML"/>
</message>
<message name="PeticionER7SoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s1:PeticionER7"/>
</message>
<message name="PeticionXMLSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s1:PeticionXML"/>
</message>
<portType name="PeticionInterconsultav01r00Soap">
    <operation name="ACKAplicacionER7">
        <input message="s0:ACKAplicacionER7SoapIn"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="ACKAplicacionXML">
        <input message="s0:ACKAplicacionXMLSoapIn"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="PeticionER7">
        <input message="s0:PeticionER7SoapIn"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="PeticionXML">
        <input message="s0:PeticionXMLSoapIn"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="PeticionInterconsultav01r00Soap" type="s0:PeticionInterconsultav01r00Soap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="ACKAplicacionER7">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/ACKAplicacionER7" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
    </operation>
    <operation name="ACKAplicacionXML">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/ACKAplicacionXML" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
    </operation>
    <operation name="PeticionER7">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionER7" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
    </operation>
    <operation name="PeticionXML">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionXML" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="PeticionInterconsultav01r00">
    <port name="PeticionInterconsultav01r00Soap" binding="s0:PeticionInterconsultav01r00Soap">
        <soap:address location="http://10.136.4.141:57772/csp/esblapalma/Servicios.Interconsulta.PeticionInterconsultav01r00.cls"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

I want to send a SOAP request to the service "PeticionXML"

I have written the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <ORM_O01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
      <MSH>
       <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
       <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
       <MSH.3>
        <HD.1>sistemaExterno</HD.1>
       </MSH.3>
       <MSH.4>
        <HD.1>12010520</HD.1>
        <HD.2>ARRECIFE, C.L.</HD.2>
       </MSH.4>
       <MSH.5>
        <HD.1>350228</HD.1>
       </MSH.5>
       <MSH.6>
        <HD.1>EXTHL7</HD.1>
       </MSH.6>
       <MSH.7>
        <TS.1>20191009103838</TS.1>
       </MSH.7>
       <MSH.8>user:pass</MSH.8>
       <MSH.9>
        <MSG.1>ORM</MSG.1>
        <MSG.2>O01</MSG.2>
        <MSG.3>ORM_O01</MSG.3>
       </MSH.9>
       <MSH.10>394522033</MSH.10>
       <MSH.11>
        <PT.1>E</PT.1>
       </MSH.11>
       <MSH.12>
        <VID.1>2.5</VID.1>
       </MSH.12>
       <MSH.13>1</MSH.13>
       <MSH.16>AL</MSH.16>
       <MSH.18>ASCII</MSH.18>
      </MSH>
       <ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <PID>
         <PID.1>1</PID.1>
         <PID.2>
          <CX.1>PRTF810354912013</CX.1>
         </PID.2>
          <PID.4>
           <CX.1>481842</CX.1>
          </PID.4>
          <PID.5>
           <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>PACIENTE1583</FN.1>
           </XPN.1>
            <XPN.2>PRUEBATF</XPN.2>
            <XPN.3>TFPRUEBA</XPN.3>
          </PID.5>
          <PID.7>
           <TS.1>19810314000000</TS.1>
          </PID.7>
          <PID.8>F</PID.8>
          <PID.13>
           <XTN.1>928000000</XTN.1>
          </PID.13>
          <PID.19>381025482253</PID.19>
          <PID.30>N</PID.30>
          <PID.31>N</PID.31>
         </PID>
         <PD1>
          <PD1.1>1</PD1.1>
         </PD1>
         <ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
          <PV1>
           <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
           <PV1.2>1</PV1.2>
           <PV1.7>
            <XCN.1>NOMBRE1 APELLIDO1 APELLIDO2</XCN.1>
           </PV1.7>
           <PV1.8>
            <XCN.1>1201050106L</XCN.1>
           </PV1.8>
           <PV1.10>APLA</PV1.10>
           <PV1.11>
            <PL.1>201052</PL.1>
           </PV1.11>
            <PV1.15>12010520</PV1.15>
            <PV1.30>00010101</PV1.30>
            <PV1.35>00010101</PV1.35>
          </PV1>
         </ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
        </ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <ORM_O01.ORDER>
         <ORC>
          <ORC.1>NW</ORC.1>
          <ORC.2>
           <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
          </ORC.2>
          <ORC.7>
           <TQ.6>1</TQ.6>
          </ORC.7>
          <ORC.8>
           <EIP.1>
            <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
           </EIP.1>
          </ORC.8>
          <ORC.10>
           <XCN.1>99999999A</XCN.1>
          </ORC.10>
          <ORC.13>
           <PL.1>CON</PL.1>
          </ORC.13>
          <ORC.16>
           <CE.1>PC</CE.1>
           <CE.2>100 PRUEBA DE ESFUERZO</CE.2>
          </ORC.16>
         </ORC>
         <ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
          <ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
           <OBR>
            <OBR.4>
             <CE.1>IAP_CAR345</CE.1>
             <CE.2>Paciente Cardiológico Continuo</CE.2>
            </OBR.4>
            <OBR.18>INC</OBR.18>
            <OBR.19>INC</OBR.19>
           </OBR>
          </ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
          <NTE>
           <NTE.3>Datos clínicos de interés%%%MOTIVO DE INTERCONSULTA: Prueba \X000d\\X000d\JUICIO DIAGNÓSTICO: AMIGDALITIS AGUDA</NTE.3>
          </NTE>
         </ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
        </ORM_O01.ORDER>
       </ORM_O01>
      </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I send the request using SoapUI it outputs:

> #ERROR 6237: Unexpected tag in XML: MSH (ends at line 5, character 12)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Mensaje SOAP mal creado.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <error xmlns="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta">
               <text>ERROR #6237: Etiqueta inesperada en la entrada XML: MSH (finaliza en la línea 5, carácter 12).</text>
            </error>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have connected to the server using Terminal, and log outputs:

```
10/14/2019 10:45:23 *********************
Input to Web service with SOAP action = "http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionXML"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <ORM_O01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
      <MSH>
       <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
       <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
       <MSH.3>
        <HD.1>sistemaExterno</HD.1>
       </MSH.3>
       <MSH.4>
        <HD.1>12010520</HD.1>
        <HD.2>ARRECIFE, C.L.</HD.2>
       </MSH.4>
       <MSH.5>
        <HD.1>350228</HD.1>
       </MSH.5>
       <MSH.6>
        <HD.1>EXTHL7</HD.1>
       </MSH.6>
       <MSH.7>
        <TS.1>20191009103838</TS.1>
       </MSH.7>
       <MSH.8>dragoaeint:pass</MSH.8>
       <MSH.9>
        <MSG.1>ORM</MSG.1>
        <MSG.2>O01</MSG.2>
        <MSG.3>ORM_O01</MSG.3>
       </MSH.9>
       <MSH.10>394522033</MSH.10>
       <MSH.11>
        <PT.1>E</PT.1>
       </MSH.11>
       <MSH.12>
        <VID.1>2.5</VID.1>
       </MSH.12>
       <MSH.13>1</MSH.13>
       <MSH.16>AL</MSH.16>
       <MSH.18>ASCII</MSH.18>
      </MSH>
       <ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <PID>
         <PID.1>1</PID.1>
         <PID.2>
          <CX.1>PRTF810354912013</CX.1>
         </PID.2>
          <PID.4>
           <CX.1>481842</CX.1>
          </PID.4>
          <PID.5>
           <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>PACIENTE1583</FN.1>
           </XPN.1>
            <XPN.2>PRUEBATF</XPN.2>
            <XPN.3>TFPRUEBA</XPN.3>
          </PID.5>
          <PID.7>
           <TS.1>19810314000000</TS.1>
          </PID.7>
          <PID.8>F</PID.8>
          <PID.13>
           <XTN.1>928000000</XTN.1>
          </PID.13>
          <PID.19>381025482253</PID.19>
          <PID.30>N</PID.30>
          <PID.31>N</PID.31>
         </PID>
         <PD1>
          <PD1.1>1</PD1.1>
         </PD1>
         <ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
          <PV1>
           <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
           <PV1.2>1</PV1.2>
           <PV1.7>
            <XCN.1>NOMBRE1 APELLIDO1 APELLIDO2</XCN.1>
           </PV1.7>
           <PV1.8>
            <XCN.1>1201050106L</XCN.1>
           </PV1.8>
           <PV1.10>APLA</PV1.10>
           <PV1.11>
            <PL.1>201052</PL.1>
           </PV1.11>
            <PV1.15>12010520</PV1.15>
            <PV1.30>00010101</PV1.30>
            <PV1.35>00010101</PV1.35>
          </PV1>
         </ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
        </ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <ORM_O01.ORDER>
         <ORC>
          <ORC.1>NW</ORC.1>
          <ORC.2>
           <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
          </ORC.2>
          <ORC.7>
           <TQ.6>1</TQ.6>
          </ORC.7>
          <ORC.8>
           <EIP.1>
            <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
           </EIP.1>
          </ORC.8>
          <ORC.10>
           <XCN.1>99999999A</XCN.1>
          </ORC.10>
          <ORC.13>
           <PL.1>CON</PL.1>
          </ORC.13>
          <ORC.16>
           <CE.1>PC</CE.1>
           <CE.2>100 PRUEBA DE ESFUERZO</CE.2>
          </ORC.16>
         </ORC>
         <ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
          <ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
           <OBR>
            <OBR.4>
             <CE.1>IAP_CAR345</CE.1>
             <CE.2>Paciente Cardiológico Continuo</CE.2>
            </OBR.4>
            <OBR.18>INC</OBR.18>
            <OBR.19>INC</OBR.19>
           </OBR>
          </ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
          <NTE>
           <NTE.3>Datos clínicos de interés%%%MOTIVO DE INTERCONSULTA: Prueba \X000d\\X000d\JUICIO DIAGNÓSTICO: AMIGDALITIS AGUDA</NTE.3>
          </NTE>
         </ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
        </ORM_O01.ORDER>
       </ORM_O01>
      </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope> 

---------------
Validate Security header: action="http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionXML"


10/14/2019 10:45:23 *********************
Output from Web service with SOAP action = "http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionXML"
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' >
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Mensaje SOAP mal creado.</faultstring>
      <detail>
    <error xmlns='http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta'>
     <text>ERROR #6237: Etiqueta inesperada en la entrada XML: MSH (finaliza en la línea 5, carácter 12).</text>
    </error>
</detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

I have also checked that client "PeticionXML" expects the parameter MSH:

```
Method operacion(ByRef MSH As WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.MSH.CONTENT(REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLREF=1,REQUIRED=1), Output SFT As %ListOfObjects(ELEMENTTYPE="WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.SFT.CONTENT",XMLPROJECTION="element",REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLNAME="SFT",XMLREF=1), ByRef MSA As WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.MSA.CONTENT(REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLREF=1,REQUIRED=1), ByRef ERR As %ListOfObjects(ELEMENTTYPE="WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.ERR.CONTENT",XMLPROJECTION="element",REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLNAME="ERR",XMLREF=1), NTE As %ListOfObjects(ELEMENTTYPE="WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.NTE.CONTENT",XMLPROJECTION="element",REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLNAME="NTE",XMLREF=1), ORRO02RESPONSE As WSCLIENTE.Farmacia.hl71.ORRO02.RESPONSE.CONTENT(REFELEMENTQUALIFIED=0,REFNAMESPACE="urn:hl7-org:v2xml",XMLNAME="ORR_O02.RESPONSE",XMLREF=1,REQUIRED=1)) [ Final, ProcedureBlock = 1, SoapBindingStyle = document, SoapBodyUse = literal, WebMethod ]
{
 Do (..WebMethod("operacion","ORR_O02")).Invoke($this,"http://[host]:[puerto]/adm/HL7Service",.MSH,.SFT,.MSA,.ERR,.NTE,.ORRO02RESPONSE)
}
```

In addition here is the code written for the service PeticionXML:

```
Method PeticionXML(mensaje As %String) As %SOAP.OneWay [ Final, ProcedureBlock = 1, SoapAction = "http://LAPALMA.Servicios/Interconsulta/PeticionXML", SoapBindingStyle = document, SoapBodyUse = literal, WebMethod ]
{
    $$$LOGINFO("test")
    set p = ##class(%GlobalCharacterStream).%New()
    do p.Write(mensaje)

    //#dim msgER7 As EnsLib.HL7.Message
    set msgER7 = ##class(EnsLib.HL7.Message).%New()
    set msgER7 = ##class(ITB.HL7.Util.Convert).XMLToER7(p,.tSC,"2.5")

    set tSC = ..SendRequestAsync("EnrutadorVisadoMedicamento",msgER7)       
    Quit $$$OK
}
```

I have also read:

[Getting error while sending SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682044/getting-error-while-sending-soap-request)
[Sending SOAP request to a specific service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596606/sending-soap-request-to-a-specific-service)
[What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

https://community.intersystems.com/question428321/answer428461
https://community.intersystems.com/post/soap-services-cach%C3%A9-os-ignore-order-elements
https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOAP_debug_info_soap_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that we need to encapsulate the HL7 ORM_O01 inside a  field. So then our request would be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:PeticionXML>
         <mensaje>
         <![CDATA[<ORM_O01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
      <MSH>
       <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
       <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
       <MSH.3>
        <HD.1>sistemaExterno</HD.1>
       </MSH.3>
       <MSH.4>
        <HD.1>12010520</HD.1>
        <HD.2>ARRECIFE, C.L.</HD.2>
       </MSH.4>
       <MSH.5>
        <HD.1>350228</HD.1>
       </MSH.5>
       <MSH.6>
        <HD.1>EXTHL7</HD.1>
       </MSH.6>
       <MSH.7>
        <TS.1>20191009103838</TS.1>
       </MSH.7>
       <MSH.8>dragoaeint:pass</MSH.8>
       <MSH.9>
        <MSG.1>ORM</MSG.1>
        <MSG.2>O01</MSG.2>
        <MSG.3>ORM_O01</MSG.3>
       </MSH.9>
       <MSH.10>394522033</MSH.10>
       <MSH.11>
        <PT.1>E</PT.1>
       </MSH.11>
       <MSH.12>
        <VID.1>2.5</VID.1>
       </MSH.12>
       <MSH.13>1</MSH.13>
       <MSH.16>AL</MSH.16>
       <MSH.18>ASCII</MSH.18>
      </MSH>
       <ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <PID>
         <PID.1>1</PID.1>
         <PID.2>
          <CX.1>PRTF810354912013</CX.1>
         </PID.2>
          <PID.4>
           <CX.1>481842</CX.1>
          </PID.4>
          <PID.5>
           <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>PACIENTE1583</FN.1>
           </XPN.1>
            <XPN.2>PRUEBATF</XPN.2>
            <XPN.3>TFPRUEBA</XPN.3>
          </PID.5>
          <PID.7>
           <TS.1>19810314000000</TS.1>
          </PID.7>
          <PID.8>F</PID.8>
          <PID.13>
           <XTN.1>928000000</XTN.1>
          </PID.13>
          <PID.19>381025482253</PID.19>
          <PID.30>N</PID.30>
          <PID.31>N</PID.31>
         </PID>
         <PD1>
          <PD1.1>1</PD1.1>
         </PD1>
         <ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
          <PV1>
           <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
           <PV1.2>1</PV1.2>
           <PV1.7>
            <XCN.1>NOMBRE1 APELLIDO1 APELLIDO2</XCN.1>
           </PV1.7>
           <PV1.8>
            <XCN.1>1201050106L</XCN.1>
           </PV1.8>
           <PV1.10>APLA</PV1.10>
           <PV1.11>
            <PL.1>201052</PL.1>
           </PV1.11>
            <PV1.15>12010520</PV1.15>
            <PV1.30>00010101</PV1.30>
            <PV1.35>00010101</PV1.35>
          </PV1>
         </ORM_O01.PATIENT_VISIT>
        </ORM_O01.PATIENT>
        <ORM_O01.ORDER>
         <ORC>
          <ORC.1>NW</ORC.1>
          <ORC.2>
           <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
          </ORC.2>
          <ORC.7>
           <TQ.6>1</TQ.6>
          </ORC.7>
          <ORC.8>
           <EIP.1>
            <EI.1>77833</EI.1>
           </EIP.1>
          </ORC.8>
          <ORC.10>
           <XCN.1>99999999A</XCN.1>
          </ORC.10>
          <ORC.13>
           <PL.1>CON</PL.1>
          </ORC.13>
          <ORC.16>
           <CE.1>PC</CE.1>
           <CE.2>100 PRUEBA DE ESFUERZO</CE.2>
          </ORC.16>
         </ORC>
         <ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
          <ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
           <OBR>
            <OBR.4>
             <CE.1>IAP_CAR345</CE.1>
             <CE.2>Paciente Cardiológico Continuo</CE.2>
            </OBR.4>
            <OBR.18>INC</OBR.18>
            <OBR.19>INC</OBR.19>
           </OBR>
          </ORM_O01.OBRRQDRQ1RXOODSODT_SUPPGRP>
          <NTE>
           <NTE.3>Datos clínicos de interés%%%MOTIVO DE INTERCONSULTA: Prueba \X000d\\X000d\JUICIO DIAGNÓSTICO: AMIGDALITIS AGUDA</NTE.3>
          </NTE>
         </ORM_O01.ORDER_DETAIL>
        </ORM_O01.ORDER>
       </ORM_O01>]]>
         </mensaje>
      </urn:PeticionXML>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The reason is that we want to prevent the XML parser from analyzing as XML, our HL7 tags, as for example  or .